# Not able to find embedded control in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and on some condition basis, I am inserting text box in it in RowDataBound:

```
 private void GetColumnWithValidation(GridViewRowEventArgs e, string columnName, int columnLength)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, columnName)).Length > columnLength)
        {
            int colindex = GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, columnName);
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Text = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, columnName));
            txt.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            txt.ID = "txt_" + i + "_" + colindex;
            lstErrorTracker.Add(i + "_" + colindex);
            //link.NavigateUrl = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PV_INVOICE_LOCATION"));
            e.Row.Cells[GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, columnName)].Controls.Add(txt);
        }
    }
```

Now if I change some data in text box of gridview I want that to be fetch whenever I click Update button. Update button is placed outside of gridview as a normal asp.net button.

But when I am trying to fetch the data I am getting null.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GVUploadDetails.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        TextBox txt= (row.Cells[3].FindControl("txt_0_3") as TextBox);
                        var test = txt.Text;
                    }
                }
```

I am getting text data as null. Please help how to get those values. And on other hand I want the entire data of the gridview as a Dataset or datatable how can I get that.

Comment: Side-Note: You don't need the `if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)` check if you enumerate all rows in a `foreach`. Only in `rowcreated` and `rowdatabound` you need this check.

Answer (score 0):

The `NamingContainer` is the `GridViewRow` not the cell, so you should use:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GVUploadDetails.Rows)
{
    TextBox txt = row.FindControl("txt_0_3") as TextBox;
    // ...
}
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, where in the page's life-cycle do you addd this `TextBox` programatically? You know that you always have to re-create it on  every consecutive postback? Do that latest in `Page_Load`, better `Page_Init`.

If you add it from `RowDataBound` you have to re-create it in `RowCreated`, otherwise it's too late to retain the `ViewState`.

Comment: I am reading data directly from excelfile that is uploaded and then creating the grid. The text box is added in rowdatabound. N I am not recreating grid any where in post back.. But it I do like row.Cell[0].Text I am getting old data

Comment: Do I need to rebind it to get the data on button click? As after button click it is going to post back and then directly to the update_click event